# .java file to run another .java (frames) through Process

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, process, runtime

Real Goal: create a program that calls other programs(lab exercises)

Current goal: Make Main.java run Lab4 a GUI program (Lab4Ans201506159.java - the filename)

Lab4Form and Lab4Intro are forms

here is the Main.java code

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Process p,p2,p3,p4;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Lab4Ans201506159.java");
    //p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Lab4Ans201506159Form.java");
    //p4 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Lab4Ans201506159Intro.java");
    p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Lab4Ans201506159");
    //p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Lab4Ans201506159");
}
```

and here is the  Lab4 code

Lab4Form and Lab4Intro are Frames

what Lab4 is trying to do displaying Lab4Intro, and when it is closed, Lab4Form would be visible

```
public class Lab4Ans201506159 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Lab4Ans201506159Intro intro = new Lab4Ans201506159Intro();
    intro.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    intro.setVisible(true);

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    //Lab4Ans201506159Form form = new Lab4Ans201506159Form();
    while(intro.isActive())
    {
    }

    if(intro.isActive() == false){
        Lab4Ans201506159Form form = new Lab4Ans201506159Form();
            form.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            form.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Problem: Running Main.java will result to a "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" in the compiler but no GUI is displayed. I need answers why it does not display or work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect only the first Process is executed, in order to be sure, have you already tried to redirect the output of Runtime.exec to the standard output

something like that:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("log.txt")));
        System.out.println("Init...");

         try {
           String line;
           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "javac Lab4Ans201506159.java" );

           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
           while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
           }
           in.close();
         }
       Thread.sleep(1000);

       Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Lab4Ans201506159" );

       BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()) );
           while ((line = in2.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
           }
           in2.close();
         }


         catch (Throwable e) {
           e.printStacktrace();
         }
    }
```

like that you can verify what is going wrong...
good luck

Comment: That code only prints "Init..." in log.txt. What does it mean?

Comment: I guess it means that there are no errors right? But still it doesn't display the GUI that it should display.

Comment: Which OS are you using? basing on the OS your are using you have different option have a look here: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Comment: I'm using windows 8 64 bit. Thanks for everything!

Comment: If you are using Windows you should try something like that:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java -jar Lab4Ans201506159.jar");

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finish my end goal which is to open Lab4. I sort of took a different method though. I suspect one of the reasons why it does not work is because my classpath must have been wrong. I could say that because I can't compile (javac) in CMD Prompt. So I fixed that, then I 'clean and build' (using Netbeans) the project(lab4,intro,form). After that, in the last line of the compiler there will be a line like "java -jar C:\sdfsafs\blablabal". That was the line I used inside runtime.exec() and it finally worked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

try {
  runProcess("java -jar \"C:\\Users\\Aldrin\\Desktop\\201506159AnsLab4\\dist\\201506159AnsLab4.jar\"");
  //runProcess("dir");
  //runProcess("java Lab4Ans201506159");
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I still have not answered why the original code does not work though.